# Django: Check that row exists in list

Tags: python, django

I want to check that `user_id` exists in the `profile_images` table from my Django template.

My Model

```
class profiles(models.Model):
    profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    -----

class Profile_images(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',default = 'uploads/no-img.jpg')
```

My View

```
def view_profiles(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        view_all_profiles = profiles.objects.all()
        profile_image = Profile_images.objects.all()
        return render_to_response('profiles/all.html', {'profiles':view_all_profiles,'profile_image':profile_image}, context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/')
```

My Template

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    <li>
        {% for image in profile_image %}
            {% ifequal image.user_id profile.user_id %}                         
                <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{image.image}}" alt="image" />
            {% endifequal %}
            <!-- i want to check here if not user_id exist in profile_images table  -->
            {% if profile.user_id not in profile_image %}
                <img src="{% static 'images/no-image.jpg' %}" alt="image" />
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

`{% if profile.user_id not in profile_image %}` is not working. I'm new to Django & python and I'm stuck here. Please suggest better ways if my code is not correct.

Comment: Why have you externalize the `profile_image` in a whole Model? Why don't you save this data in `profiles`?

Comment: @MaximeLorant . first I'm new to Django . Second I'm saving that details not at same time & some fields value null false. So I'm worried if profile image cannot save without other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your view you could get all user_ids with a profile image, something like:

```
user_ids_with_profile_images = Profile_images.objects.all().values_list('user_id', flat=True)
```

Then in your template you could check if `profile.user_id not in user_ids_with_profile_images`.

---

It might actually be a little cleaner to loop through all the users with profiles in your system and get their profile images through the foreign key, instead of looping through all the profiles and trying to get the users...

Answer (score 1):

This is really a design problem, you've got a separate model specifically for a profile image when that could just be a field on the profile model itself.

```
class Profile(models.Model): # convention is to use a non-plural name for models
    # No need to explicitly set the primary key, this will be added automatically
    # profile_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/',default = 'uploads/no-img.jpg')
    -----
```

Now it would just be a case of using `{{ profile.image }}` with no need for any additional looking up.